# Cannot prevent the datepicker from showing after making a field readonly

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker

There is a field attached to `datepicker` :

```
...
<input type="text" class="datepicker chp_" name="dateDebut" />
...

<?php $this->load->view("footer"); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var idSpecialite = "<?php echo $this->session->userdata('idSpecialite'); ?>";

    if (idSpecialite != 4) {

        $("#tab1").find(".chp_").each(function(){
            $(this).attr("readonly","");
            if ($(this).hasClass("datepicker")) {
                $(this).removeClass("datepicker");
            }
        });

    }

});
```

In the footer there is this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     ...
    $(function() {

        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            language: 'fr',
            autoclose: true
        });

    });
</script>
```

As you can see I want the field to be non-editable in a particular condition. But at runtime when I click the field then the picker still shows and the field's value can be changed when selecting a date ! So how to not show the picker in this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok , I used the `disabled` attribute then the picker did not show :

```
if (idSpecialite != 4) {

    $("#tab1").find(".chp_").each(function(){
        $(this).attr("disabled",true);
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use this code to make it read-only

```
$this.attr('readonly','readonly');
```

also make sure that the value of idSpecialite  is not 4, you can convert the result to integer to see it, like this:

```
var idSpecialite = parseInt("<?php echo $this->session->userdata('idSpecialite'); ?>");
```